# #1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date' when trying to create a new column

Tags: database, mysql, sql, table, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a new column inside the `wp_posts` table but I am getting the error `#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'` when I try and save it. What I am trying to do is, I am getting some data from an external API that I am saving in my Database and then I was to be able to check if the data exists in my DB, which is why I am trying to create a column inside the `wp_posts` table to save the unique ID of the data from the API. The following is the SQL query. I am trying to do this using the PhpMyAdmin.

`` ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`  ADD `apipostid` VARCHAR(20) NULL  AFTER `ID`; ``

Comment: I wouldn't recommend altering the `wp_posts` table. Instead, add the apipostid as post meta. See, eg, [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution. I am not an expert. But the following helped solve my problem and I can add columns using the PhpMyAdmin without getting any errors.

I went over to the SQL tab and then I ran the following query
`show variables like 'sql_mode';`
Then in order to remove i ran the following query
`set global sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

This helped solve my problem.